# how to use Kinetic AbsolutePosition property

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I want to understand how I would draw a line between two shapes that are nested in other groups/layers. Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/6UhNp/) which illustrates what I mean. As you can tell, when the coordinates in use are in the same layer, it is trivial to draw line. When the coordinates are nested inside other groups/layers, then the outcome is not as expected. Try moving the right box around to see the less than desirable results.

Could someone please show me how I translate coordinates from one layer into that of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some Xs where Ys should be, here's a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6UhNp/8/.

This works as far as you have specified, so you were using it right, but it does not work when you zoom in and out.

I have seen that zoom function you're using floating around recently, and I don't feel it's a correct solution. I haven't sat down to work it out yet, though.

Comment: Problem is that I am trying to solve a problem that I don't fully understand. I know this has something to do with the transformation matrix, but Kineticjs is more designed to avoid using those.

Comment: I know its a pain to figure out 'the maths' if its not immediately apparent. You shouldn't need to use transformation matrices though; as you said, Kinetic tends to avoid them. I do plan on tackling the zoom function soon so hopefully I can get something up for you to look at.